# Create a div with jquery and open it in full screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a `div` with jQuery from Javascript , and open it in full screen.

Can i create a div directly from JavaScript without having to first create from html , and then make it visible from Javascript with jQuery or CSS?

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem in this way:

```
var mydiv = "<div>....</div>";

$('body').append(mydiv);
```

Comment: what.....? sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: @Jai : in my page there are some objects, and when I click on a certain object, call a function in Javascript 

I would like this javascript function would allow me to create a div and open it in full page

Comment: You may like to look at the relatively new JavaScript fullscreen API: http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen. It can be used to make any element appear as fullscreen in supported browsers, although it is mostly used for videos or html5 canvas (e.g. for games)

Comment: @user2693765I : did not mean that type of fullscreen, I just need the div that is as large as the size of the page 

and for what I know how to do, but I do not know how to create a div with jquery and open it without having previously created

Comment: $('body').append('<div>you content</div>'); i think this u asking for

Comment: I have perfect ans with js fiddle , not able to post answer , due to this question is on hold :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot show anything in the browser unless in is added to the html of the page you are on.

you can append your div to the html, set its `position:fixed;` and left/top to 0, and width/height to the size of the document/window

Comment: or `html5` [fullscreen api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)